# How can I active or passive options Django Admin

Tags: python, html, django

I have a form option in my Django application. I want to be able to activate or deactivate some options from the admin panel. How can I go about this?

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
           <input type="text" placeholder='Username' class="form-control" name="username">
           <br>
           <label for="type">Bonus Türü</label>
                <select name="bonuses" id="test" id='testvalue' class="form-control">
                      <option selected value="0">Please select</option>
                      <option value="2">Taste </option>                                    
                      <option value="36206">Taste 1 </option>  
                      <option value="58013">Taste 2</option>
                      <option value="55908">Taste 3</option>                                
                      <option value="21310">Taste 4</option>
                </select>
    </div>
```

For example, with a feature I added to the admin panel, I want to disable the 4th option and activate it whenever I want.

This is my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Bonusrequest
 
class adminPlus(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ("username","name","bonus","result","created","descrpt")

admin.site.register(Bonusrequest,adminPlus)
```

Comment: Please add more information to your question. Such as, how do you define your form? Where those options come from? Maybe share your `BonusRequest` model etc.

Answer (score 0):

from django.db import models

```
class Bonusrequest(models.Model):
    

    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Kullanici Adi')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Ad Soyad")
    bonus = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Bonus Turu')
    result = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Sonuc')
    created = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Tarih")
    descrpt = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name="Aciklama", null=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Bonus Talepleri"
```

And this is models.py